# QGIS Installation on Mac - Mac doesn't accept QGIS as a trusted developer

Tags: qgis, installation, mac

I am trying to install QGIS on a MacBook, using MacOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6. For some reason, having installed Python 3.6, my Mac refuses to use the installer saying that QGIS is not a trusted developer. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You may try alternative MacOS [QGIS installer](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/) by NextGIS. At this moment 2.18.25 QGIS version only. This installer signed and indicated as trusted.

[image]

**Disclosure**: I'm developer at NextGIS.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the system preferences and click "security".

Under the general tab you will see a warning towards the bottom of the screen saying something like "[name of program] was blocked from opening".  Next to this warning there will be an Open Anyway button.

If you click this the installer will open.